# Ubuntu 22.04 freezing - need help with diagnosis

Tags: 22.04, freeze

My Ubuntu 22.04  periodically freezes. It can happen at any moment, but it appears to occur most frequently while using a web browser. I'm uncertain whether this is a software or hardware issue.

I'm attaching the general boot logs to help you better understand my issue.

1. `dmesg` logs - https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ij2ceQBwwZXwyFRSN2-PIG-mGhs6kJu/view?usp=sharing.
2. `journalctl -xe` - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZaqmpHns11lua5v-GfQFpdco3WTcHyw/view?usp=sharing.

```
Nov 07 11:45:48 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to send h2c command
Nov 07 11:45:51 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:02 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:03 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:04 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:05 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:06 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:06 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to send h2c command
Nov 07 11:46:19 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:20 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:21 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:26 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Nov 07 11:46:27 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Nov 07 11:46:27 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Nov 07 11:46:32 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:33 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Nov 07 11:46:46 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Nov 07 11:46:56 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Nov 07 11:47:01 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx gnome-shell[2519]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Nov 07 11:47:21 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:47:48 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Nov 07 11:49:04 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Nov 07 11:49:05 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:49:06 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:49:21 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 07 11:49:33 valerii-HP-Laptop-14s-dq2xxx wpa_supplicant[725]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
```

3. General logs - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YOUT96pAD6YCEQWl3bR-l-kKt6zm9BT8/view?usp=sharing.

```
11:41:52 kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to send h2c command
11:20:23 bluetoothd: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
11:20:14 kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to send h2c command
11:19:54 bluetoothd: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
11:19:16 kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to send h2c command
09:18:24 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
09:18:20 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
09:18:20 kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to send h2c command
09:18:19 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
09:18:13 kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to send h2c command
09:18:04 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
09:18:03 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
09:18:01 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
```

Comment: The people around here that can help you do not like links, especially for guugle-drive.<br/>Can you edit your question and paste in the relevant text (not all of it) so we can dig in? Maybe use the name of your browser firefox or mozilla as a searchword in a piped output such as `dmesg | grep -i <searchword>`

Comment: what is the output of `free -h` command in terminal?

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.5Gi       1.7Gi       337Mi       422Mi       1.5Gi       1.1Gi
Swap:          4.2Gi       107Mi       4.1Gi

Answer (score 0):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: 22.04 does not use a swap partition (unless the user specifically installed that way). But you could try the swapiness command.